# Python ctypes, C++ object destruction

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

Consider the following python ctypes - c++ binding:

```
// C++
class A
{
public:
    void someFunc();
};

A* A_new() { return new A(); }
void A_someFunc(A* obj) { obj->someFunc(); }
void A_destruct(A* obj) { delete obj; }

# python
from ctypes import cdll

libA = cdll.LoadLibrary(some_path)

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = libA.A_new()

    def some_func(self):
        libA.A_someFunc(self.obj)
```

What's the best way to delete the c++ object, when the python object is not needed any more.

[edit]
I added the delete function that was suggested, however the problem remains by whom and when the function is called. It should be as convenient as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could implement the `__del__` method, which calls a destructor function you would have to define:

**C++**

```
class A
{
public:
    void someFunc();
};

A* A_new() { return new A(); }
void delete_A(A* obj) { delete obj; }
void A_someFunc(A* obj) { obj->someFunc(); }
```

**Python**

```
from ctypes import cdll

libA = cdll.LoadLibrary(some_path)

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        fun = libA.A_new
        fun.argtypes = []
        fun.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        self.obj = fun()

    def __del__(self):
        fun = libA.delete_A
        fun.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        fun.restype = None
        fun(self.obj)

    def some_func(self):
        fun = libA.A_someFunc
        fun.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        fun.restype = None
        fun(self.obj)
```

Also note that you left out the `self` parameter on the `__init__` method. Futhermore, you have to specify the return type/argument type explicitly, because ctypes defaults to 32 bit integers, while a pointer is likely 64 bits on modern systems.

Some think `__del__` is evil. As an alternative, you can use `with` syntax:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        fun = libA.A_new
        fun.argtypes = []
        fun.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
        self.obj = fun()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        fun = libA.delete_A
        fun.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        fun.restype = None
        fun(self.obj)

    def some_func(self):
        fun = libA.A_someFunc
        fun.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
        fun.restype = None
        fun(self.obj)

with A() as a:
    # Do some work
    a.some_func()
```

Comment: When will the __del__ function be called?

Comment: When `A`'s reference count hits zero, just before the object is cleaned up.

Comment: Are there any guarantees on when that happens? Can't find them in the python documentation. Does this mean python decides when `__del__` is executed?

Comment: @tauran: See [this](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-reference-count) and [this](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ext/refcounts.html) for information about reference counts

Answer (score 2):

In general, dlls should provide a method for cleaning up object that they created. That way, memory allocation is encapsulated within the dll. This means, your dll should probably expose a method like `void A_delete(A*)`.

Answer (score 2):

Export a function from the DLL the frees the object. You have to do this in order to ensure that the same memory management mechanism is used to free the object that was in charge when the object was allocated.