# deallocating memory for objects returned to python through ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using ctypes for extending my c functions in MyDll  to python.

```
from ctypes import cdll
libX = cdll.LoadLibrary("d:\\MyTestProject\\debug\\MyDll.dll")
```

further in the .py file i have a class the methods of which call the functions in MyDll through ctypes.

```
Class MyTestClass:
       def __init__(self,id):
           libA.MyTestClassInDLL_new.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
           self.obj = libA.MyTestClassInDLL_new(id)
```

the corresponding c function MyTestClassInDLL_new has been defined in MyDll as -

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void * MyTestClassInDLL_new(char* id) 
{ 
     pTestObject = new CMyTestClassInDLL(CString(id)); 
     return (void *)pTestObject;    
}
```

Note I am using new to instantiate this object in my vc++ dll and returning the pointer to it. I have set the restype of this function in the .py file as  ctypes.c_void_p.

The script that I execute contains the following -

```
testob = MyTestClass("5")
```

this works fine. the testob that i obtain here is used further to call its methods which internally call the c functions from MyDll.

However the object was created using new in MyDll and returned through MyTestClassInDLL_new() function. How is this object to be destroyed ? somewhere i need to use delete  pTestObject so that its destructor is called which does the cleanup and the memory is deallocated.

Answer (score 4):

I typically handle this by adding an extern destroy object function that I can pass the pointer back to and delete it.

CPP:

```
SomeClass* createObj()
{
    return new SomeClass();
}

void destroyObj(SomeClass* pObj){
  delete pObj;
  pObj = NULL;
}
```

H:

```
extern "C" {
  SomeClass* createObj();
  void destroyObj(SomeClass*);
}
```

PY:

```
class SomeObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.soLib = cdll.LoadLibrary(PATH_SO)
        _createObj = self.soLib.createObj
        _createObj.restype = POINTER(c_long)

        self._objRef = _createObj()
        ## do stuff with self._objRef

    def __del__(self):
        self.soLib.destroyObj(self._objRef)
```

Comment: I have done exactly the same. The problem is __del__ does not get called at the end of the script execution. In what way can i ensure that __del__ is called after the testob goes out of scope ( that is the script gets over ?) setting testob = None at the end of the script calls __del__ . but that may not be the right way.

Comment: If the script exits the memory will be cleaned up.  If it bothers you explicitly call the del function:  del testob.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724987/python-ctypes-c-object-destruction