# How to pass pointer back in ctypes?

Tags: python, pointers, dll, char, ctypes

Don't know much about ctypes, just recently began working with it.

I have a simple function in C-like dll which returns a pointer to the dynamically generated string.
It is working fine, but, because i manually allocated memory for the string, i should free it after use.

I have something like this:

```
extern "C" char* DLL_EXPORT func(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    return getSomeString(str1, str2);
}

// Goal is to call this function correctly from Python.    
extern "C" void DLL_EXPORT freeMem(void *mem)
    {
        if(mem!=NULL)
            delete mem;
    }
```

But i don't have any idea, how can i pass received pointer back for deletion in Python?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398575/deallocating-memory-for-objects-returned-to-python-through-ctypes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track.

```cpp
// TestDLL.cpp
#include <string.h> // strcpy

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* stringdup(const char* str) {
    char* p = new char[strlen(str)+1];
    strcpy(p,str);
    return p;
}

// if you have no good reason to use void*, use the type
// you've allocated. while it usually works for built-in
// types, it wouldn't work for classes (it wouldn't call
// the destructor)
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void stringfree(char* ptr) {
    // you don't need to check for 0 before you delete it,
    // but if you allocate with new[], free with delete[] !
    delete [] ptr; 
}
```

And in python:

```py
# Test.py
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.TestDLL

# this creates a c-style char pointer, initialized with a string whose
# memory is managed by PYTHON! do not attempt to free it through the DLL!
cstr = ctypes.c_char_p("hello ctypes")

# call the dll function that returns a char pointer 
# whose memory is managed by the DLL.
p = lib.stringdup(cstr)

# p is just an integer containing the memory address of the 
# char array. therefore, this just prints the address:
print p

# this prints the actual string
print ctypes.c_char_p(p).value

# free the memory through the DLL
lib.stringfree(p)
```

Comment: `stringdup.restype` needs to be set to a pointer type, such as `POINTER(c_char)` since the default result type is a 32-bit `int`. To get a Python string, you can use `cast(p, c_char_p).value` or
 `c_char_p.from_buffer(p).value`.

Answer (score 14):

Normally each function you use in `ctypes` should have its arguments and return type declared so Python can check for the correct number and type of arguments and convert Python object arguments to the correct C data objects.  Unfortunately in this case, the normal return value for `func` would be `c_char_p`, but `ctypes` tries to be helpful and convert a `c_char_p` return value to a Python string, losing access to the raw C pointer value.  Instead, you can declare the return type as `POINTER(c_char)` and use `cast` to retrieve the string value, which leaves the return value a `LP_c_char` object that can be freed.

Here's an example.  Note that declaring the correct `.restype` is especially important for 64-bit Python, since the default return type is `c_int` (32-bit) and a 64-bit pointer could be truncated.  This code is tested with both 32- and 64-bit builds.

test.c

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API char* func(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
    size_t len = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1;
    char* tmp = malloc(len);
    strcpy_s(tmp, len, str1);
    strcat_s(tmp, len, str2);
    return tmp;
}

API void freeMem(void *mem) {
    free(mem);
}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.func.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,ct.c_char_p
dll.func.restype = ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)
dll.freeMem.argtypes = ct.c_void_p,
dll.freeMem.restype = None

# Helper function to extract the return value as a Python object
# and always free the pointer.
def freeMem(a,b):
    p = dll.func(b'abcdef', b'ghijkl')
    print(p)
    s = ct.cast(p, ct.c_char_p).value
    dll.freeMem(p)
    return s

print(freeMem(b'abcdef', b'ghijkl'))
```

Output:

```
<ctypes.LP_c_char object at 0x00000279D7959DC0>
b'abcdefghijkl'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
#cdll.execute.restype = ctypes.c_char_p               # failed to free
cdll.execute.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)  # worked

p = cdll.execute('...')
print(
    ctypes.cast(p, ctypes.c_char_p).value.decode('utf-8')
)

cdll.free_pointer(p)
```