# How to return pointer string with ctypes in python 2.7

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ctypes

I am working on implementation of new fiscal device. And it is using OPOS / UPOS library for communication. I am very new to `ctypes` and have no experience with C at all. However, I have managed to make it work, mostly.

But I am having issues with returning a string from generalist method `DirectIO`. documentation says: "This command should be used immediately after EndFiscalReceipt() to retrieve unique ID of latest receipt"

" Parameters:
 – Data [in]
 Ignored.
 – Obj [in/out]
 Value to be read."

And adds .NET example under it:

```
int iData = 0;
string strReferenceID = "";
fiscalPrinter.EndFiscalReceipt();
fiscalPrinter.DirectIO(CMD_EKASA_RECEIPT_ID, ref iData, ref strReferenceID);
// strReferenceID will contain latest receipt ID, e.g. "O−7DBCDA8A56EE426DBCDA8A56EE426D1A"
```

*the first parameter (CMD_EKASA_RECEIPT_ID) is the command executed, thats why its not listed above.*

However, python is not .NET and I have never been working with .NET.

I have been following instructions in ctypes doku (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html), defiend this methods arguments and return in init:

```
self.libc.DirectIO.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_char_p]
self.libc.DirectIO.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
```

Than tried different ways to retrieve reply string, but neither of these does work in my case:

```
s = ""
c_s = ctypes.c_char_p(s)
result = self.send_command(CMD_EKASA_RECEIPT_ID, 0, c_s)

p = ctypes.create_string_buffer(40)
poin = ctypes.pointer(p)
result = self.send_command(CMD_EKASA_RECEIPT_ID, 0, poin)

p = ctypes.create_string_buffer(40)
result = self.send_command(CMD_EKASA_RECEIPT_ID, 0, p)

s = ctypes.create_string_buffer('\000' * 32)
result = self.send_command(CMD_EKASA_RECEIPT_ID, 0, s)
```

the string object I have created is allways empty, a.k.a. `""` after caling the Cmethod, just like I have created it.

However, there is one more thing, that does not make sense to me. My colleague showed me, how you can see method arguments and return in header file. For this one, there is this:

```
int DirectIO(int iCommand, int* piData, const char* pccString);
```

Which means, it returns integer? If I am not mistaken.

so, what I am thinking is, that I have to pass to the method some pointer to a string, created in python, and C will change it, into what I should read. Thus, I think my way of thinking about solution is right.

I have also tried this approach, but that does not work for me either [How to pass pointer back in ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908226/how-to-pass-pointer-back-in-ctypes)

and I am starting to feel desperate. Not sure if I understand the problem correctly and looking for a solution is right place.

Comment: What is the C prototype for DirectIO?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

There is `linux` in the tag, but OPOS does not work on linux.

Or are you working in an emulation environment such as Wine?

In any case, if you don't have the right environment, you can get into trouble with a little bit of nothing.

First, work in a Windows 32-bit environment, create something that works there, and then port it to another environment.

Since OPOS uses OLE/COM technology, the first package to use is `win32com` or `comtypes`.

---

UnifiedPOS is a conceptual specification and there are no actual software components.

There are three types of software that actually run: OPOS, JavaPOS, and POS for.NET.
OPOS and POS for.NET only work in a Windows 32-bit environment.

Only JavaPOS can work in a Linux environment, and it is usually only available from Java.

If you want to make something in Python, you need to create a Wrapper (or glue) library that calls Java from Python.

---

If the C interface UnifiedPOS(OPOS) is running on Linux without using the Windows emulator or the Wrapper for Java, it may be an original library/component created by the printer vendor with reference to UnifiedPOS.

In that case, I think that the detailed specification can only be heard from the vendor who created it.

---

To explain, DirectIO method and DirectIOEvent are defined as method/event that vendors can freely define and use.

Therefore, only method/event names and parameters are defined in the UnifiedPOS document.

It is necessary to ask the vendor who provides the DirectIO method/DirectIOEvent what function the specific vendor's service object has, and it is up to the vendor to determine what the parameter means is.

The OPOS specification was absorbed by UnifiedPOS from the middle, but until then it existed as a single specification.

The rest of the name is here.  [MCS: OPOS Releases](http://monroecs.com/oposreleases.htm)

This is the root of the return value of the method of your library being integer.

By the way, this is the latest UnifiedPOS specification for now.
[Document -- retail/17-07-32 (UnifiedPOS Retail Peripheral Architecture, Version 1.14.1)](https://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?retail/17-07-32.pdf)

Comment: It is package created for Linux enviroment. they call it UnifiedPOS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnifiedPOS), which is basically OPOS derivation. But the UPOS tag does not work here. It is basicaly mostly same library methods wise. I have no problem to connect with device, I can even print fiscal bill without issue. My troubles start when I have to retrieve some value from device. My problem is more about `ctypes` and `python` than the library. the OPOS tag can be dropped if it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. The whole thing was, in allocating of memory. Every example on the net that I have readed did create empty string, like `s = ""`. But, that is not correct!

When allocated empty string `""` C library have had no memory where to write result.

this was almost correct approach,

```
self.libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(LIB_PATH)
self.libc.DirectIO.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_char_p]
result_s = ctypes.c_char_p("")
log.info('S address: %s | S.value: "%s"' % (result_s, result_s.value))
self.libc.DirectIO(CMD_EKASA_RECEIPT_ID, 0, result_s)
log.info('S address: %s | S.value: "%s"' % (result_s, result_s.value))
```

returns:

```
S address: c_char_p(140192115373700) | S.value: ""
S address: c_char_p(140192115373700) | S.value: ""
```

**it needed just a small modification:**

```
self.libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(LIB_PATH)
self.libc.DirectIO.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_int32, ctypes.c_char_p]
result_s = ctypes.c_char_p(" " * 10)
log.info('S address: %s | S.value: %s' % (result_s, result_s.value))
self.libc.DirectIO(CMD_EKASA_RECEIPT_ID, 0, result_s)
log.info('S address: %s | S.value: %s' % (result_s, result_s.value))
```

now, printing `result_s` after calling `self.libc.DirectIO` does return different string, than it was before call.

```
S address: c_char_p(140532072777764) | S.value: "          "
S address: c_char_p(140532072777764) | S.value: "0-C12A22F5"
```

Comment: You can use `ctypes.create_string_buffer(10)` instead of `ctypes.c_char_p(' '*10)`.