# Is there a way to delete pointer passed to python?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, pointers, ctypes

I have a function in C++ that passed array to python code. As I understand I need to `delete[]` it, so memory would not accumulate.
Here's how it works in C++ side:

```
extern "C" char* func()
{
    char* abc = new char[1000000]; //about 1MB
    return abc;
}
```

So in python I just receive this data via ctypes and do what I do. I call it over and over again. So that is going to overflow my RAM eventually? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [deallocating memory for objects returned to python through ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398575/deallocating-memory-for-objects-returned-to-python-through-ctypes)

Comment: Create another C++ func to receive and free a pointer. Then call it from your Python code.

Comment: If you could elaborate, how would another function have access to such pointer?

Comment: @Name, see the top answer in the post linked by JohnSmith

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `unique_ptr`! It deletes himself when the function scope is terminated.

```
unique_ptr<char> func()
{
    unique_ptr<char> abc (new char[1000000]); //about 1MB
    return abc;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. You can't `extern "C"` a unique pointer.

Comment: (after your edit) With name mangling, not sure you could use it without `extern "C"` from Python...

Comment: Sorry... you're right! What about a ```shared_ptr?```